# Proof if $x+y=0$, then $xy \leq 0$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

For all $x,y ∈ \mathbb R$, if $x + y = 0$ then $xy \leq 0$. Decide whether this is true or false.

I assume this is true since one of $x$ or $y$ needs to be positive while the other is negative, so their product is negative, but how would would i go about proving this? Would this be right:

Let $x = 2k$ and $y = -2k$, such that $k \in \mathbb N$. Then $x + y = 0$.

So $xy = -4k^2$ which is less than $0$, hence this is true.

Comment: You say $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, but then assume that they are even? You are on the right track, but the $k$ there is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Simply observe $x = -y$ and hence $xy = -y^2$.

Comment: Since $y = -x,$ $xy$ cannot be positive, but it will be $0$ if $x=y=0.$

Comment: You cannot assume one must be positive and the other negative. They might both be $0$ but that's an easy case to consider. Are you working with a particular set of axioms?

Comment: It is very easy to prove $X^2\ge 0$ for all $X\in\mathbb{R}.$ Now observe that $x+y=0\implies x^2+y^2=-2xy.$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This is your fourteenth question here. You ought to be using MathJax by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You complicated more then needed and it is not false, but incomplete because your case just applies for even numbers, you should also consider the case x=2k+1(odds)
A more simpler way is:

if x+y=0, then x=-y, therefore $xy=(-y)(y)=-y^2 \leq 0$ for all real.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $xy>0;$

Then $x,y >0$, or $x,y <0.$

In in either case $x+y \not =0,$ which contradicts the assumption.